# Scroll an element to center

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.uitest

I started using Xamarin UI Test for my Automated tests nearly 9 months ago. Recent updates to the UI of the app I'm working on made it so the elements behind Appbar and Navbar are considered displayed on the screen, which leads to a Tap on the Appbar/Navbar and not the actual element, I asked the devs on my team if there's anything they can do but they couldn't change that weird behaviour from those 2 elements. I've been looking for a way to scroll an element to the center/middle of the view but in vain. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this centred scroll? or a solution for this issue?

Here's the code I usually use :

```
app.ScrollDownTo(x=>x.Id("Element ID"));
```

I use Appcenter to run my tests on multiple devices, this is the method I use when I encounter this problem, I can make it work for one device but it probably does not work on other screen sizes :

```
//I scroll little by little until I find my element
for( int i = 0; app.Query(x=>x.Id("Element ID")).length == 0 && i<10; i++){

//this code performs a very small scroll gesture
app.ScrollDown(x=>x.ClassFull("UIScrollView"));

}
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: **1)** Please add to question relevant code. I understand that you don't have code that performs the desired scroll, but if you want useful help, show the code you wish to add that to. **2)** No, but its probably possible to do a calculation in code-behind that gets a specified element APPROXIMATELY in the middle of scroll area's height. There's no point in speculating further how to do so, without actual code. **3)** Sounds like your *underlying* problem is what the devs say they can't fix. *They* could post a question with *that* problem's code; there likely exists some technique to fix.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello, just added the codes I usually use, I hope that made it clearer. Tell me if anything else needs to be done. I'm very new to stack overflow, I apologise for this lacklustre post.